# -mno-fused-madd error when trying to pip install django-toolbelt

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

```
clang: warning: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

I can not pip install. Someone said it had to do with an XCode installation and to do the following
`sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install django-toolbelt`
which I tried. This ended up with a "successful" installation but when I run `foreman start`as specified in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django, it just says

```
20:48:31 web.1  | started with pid 95750
```

and then doesn't actually start anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing toolbelt with following way

> https://toolbelt.heroku.com/osx

And seems like you successfully installed toolbelt. Once time i also had same issue. foreman start success but noting performed but i can able to deploy and that is working fine